# separating a string with strtok

Tags: c, eclipse, string, strtok

I'm looking to separate a line (given as one string) into words. for example:
"     Hello        world". I can have one or more tabs or spaces between the words and in the beginning. I'm trying to do something like this:
(findCommand is a function and line is the string I get as input, for this part I only need the first 2 words)

```
CommandResult findCommand (const char* line){
    char* commandLine = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
    strcpy(commandLine, line);
    char space[] = " \t";
    char* word1 = strtok(commandLine,space);
    char* word2 = strtok(NULL,space);
```

I've tried to run this in Eclipse with different variations of spaces and tabs. some of them worked fine, on others I get a sigmentation fault and I can't figure out why.

Comment: where do you get segfault and for which input? please include those infos in your post.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(line) + 1)`

Comment: for example "     hgyj    kjsdlkjdalkj" there's a bunch of spaces and tabs before and between the words. they're erased for some reason when I send the comment

Comment: or just use [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/strdup.html).

Comment: You still have a sizeof() in your malloc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
char* commandLine = malloc(sizeof(strlen(line)));
```

is wrong. You shouldn't use `sizeof` here, and *certainly* not on the result of calling `strlen()`. The above is the same as:

```
char *commandLine = malloc(sizeof (size_t));
```

since the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`. Thus, the actual `strlen()` return value is ignored.

The proper code is:

```
char *commandLine = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

since you must add 1 for the terminator, which is not included in the length returned by `strlen()`.

There is no need for any `sizeof` here, since you're very obviously working with characters.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I just used sizeof for memory allocations for other types so I automatically put it here too. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc((strlen(line) + 1)* sizeof(char))` instead of `malloc(sizeof(strlen(line)))`.
You allocate only space for an integer because sizeof returns an integer.

Comment: -1 for not including space for the terminator, and recommending `sizeof (char)`.

Comment: It's nevermind for a char if you use it or not. A char is a byte, but by convention you should use it, if you allocate space for a specific datatype, as an example `long int`.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice, since it adds nothing and just obscures the code. Also, your usage is even wrong since the `1` is not included in the scaling anyway.

Comment: have corrected this. You don't use sizeof because this works only for datatype char. If he allocate space in the future and don't use sizeof for example an `long int`, it could throw a segfault. This is why i have included `sizeof`

Comment: Downvote removed. If you insist on using `sizeof`, I think the proper form is `commandLine = malloc((1 + strlen(line)) * sizeof *commandLine);`, so you don't repeat the type name but instead lock it to a variable.